# Fixed position menu and internal links?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure I worded that right as I am a beginner, but I am trying to do a fixed position nav menu that always stays at the top (I have that part figured out) and a link that takes you to a lower section of the page below while keeping the menu at the top.

Ive got the menu to stay fixed and it does jump, however because of my 100px nav menu in its fixed position, it covers up 100px of the section it jumped to.

I guess I am wondering what is the best way to get it to land 100px above the section so none of it gets cut off.

```css
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
 nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: xx-large;
 padding-top: 40px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #A7E1E8;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<nav><a href="#content2">JUMP</a></nav>
<section id="content1"></section>
<section id="content2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
  <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>
<section id="content1"></section>
```

Comment: This is easiest achieved with iframe, but that's oldskool. Now the cool way is to find a JS library for it - there's many that do just this. They even have smooth scrolling sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using many techniques, but the simplest solution would be using Jquery. The code bellow should help you.
It gets the offset of the container2 and scroll to it, minus 140px, with the click of the link.

EDIT:
Updated the code to get the anchor in the click of the link

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav a").on('click',function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(link).offset().top - 140)},'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0 0;
  padding:0 0;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
 nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: xx-large;
 padding-top: 40px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #A7E1E8;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#content1">JUMP 1</a>
  <a href="#content2">JUMP 2</a>
</nav>
<section id="content1"></section>
<section id="content2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
  <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>
<section id="content1"></section>
```

Comment: Ahh that is very cool.  I am clueless when it comes to JS, I think I know how to implement your example but what properties would I change if I had multiple nav links?  I know I would change #content2 but how do I tell the scripts to do it at the for the other nav links?

Comment: I updated the code to make what you want. On the click of the link, you should get the atribute "href", so you will know which container the script should scroll to.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me a ton of time and grief.

Comment: Ah oops sorry about that I am new here, accepted and thanks again.

Comment: Hey I implemented this into the site I was working on and it works great!  However, I was thinking about making my Nav menu % based and not a fixed height.  Is it possible to modify the script so that it would work with a height percentage?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code and prevent the navigation from laying itself above your content you can adjust the margin/padding of your content boxes.

If you want to adjust the spacing for all content boxes you can add this to your css

```
section {padding-top:140px;}
```

This should work fine. Its 140px because you add 100px for the navigation and 40px because the padding-top of the navigation.

Heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8cfygn86/

If you have further questions let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the response, that would definitely work but it could hurt the look of it if someone chooses to manually scroll right?because I would have blank spots?

Comment: Yes! This answer was based on the case, that you want an fast an easy css only solution. jQuery of course is the much smoother, but although difficult solution! I think the solution Renan suggested works like charm!