# Internal links with a fixed div at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I've seen a similar question at [Fixed position menu and internal links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440706/fixed-position-menu-and-internal-links) but my case seems to me a bit different, and the proposed solutions don't work for me.

I have a fixed "dashboard" at the top of the screen, and a line of "cards" below it. For a faster browsing there are internal links to the "cards".

The problem is when I click the internal links the top of the "card" goes at the top of the screen, and it is covered by the "dashboard".

Example at https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/bevvw4zp/1/

CSS:

```
#Dashboard {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 32px;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
    background: #cf0;
    text-align: center;
}
#TheText {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.box {
    border: 3px solid #080;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Dashboard">The general dashboard</div>
<div id="TheText">
    <div id="nav"> <a href="#box_1">box 1</a>
        <br /> <a href="#box_2">box 2</a>
        <br /> <a href="#box_3">box 3</a>
        <br /> <a href="#box_4">box 4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box_1" class="box">this is the box 1
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br /><a href="#nav">back to top</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box_2" class="box">this is the box 2
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br /><a href="#nav">back to top</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box_3" class="box">this is the box 3
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br /><a href="#nav">back to top</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box_4" class="box">this is the box 4
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br /><a href="#nav">back to top</a>
    </div>
```

I've the following constrains:

- no jQuery (but I can write the same code in vanilla JS)
- no `margin-top` higher than the dashboard, or there will be too much space between the cards
- no `padding-top`, it makes the cards look "ugly"

Is there a way to deal with this better than a call to a `.scrollTo()`?

---

**Solved**

The `.scrollTo()` solution is not so bad, after all. See it at work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/bevvw4zp/4/ (hint: reduce the output pane height to show just a single box to appreciate the effect)

HTML:

```
<div id="Dashboard">The general dashboard
    <select onchange="showBox(this.value)">
        <option value="">Pick a box</option>
        <option value="1">box 1</option>
        <option value="2">box 2</option>
        <option value="3">box 3</option>
        <option value="4">box 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="TheText">
    <div id="box_1" class="box">this is the box 1
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c</div>
    <div id="box_2" class="box">this is the box 2
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c</div>
    <div id="box_3" class="box">this is the box 3
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c</div>
    <div id="box_4" class="box">this is the box 4
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c
        <br />a b c</div>
</div>
```

CSS: as above

Javascript:

```
function showBox(el_id) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var element = document.getElementById('box_' + el_id);
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var TheTop = rect.top;
    window.scrollTo(0, TheTop - 40);
}
```

The `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` is to reset the box coordinates, otherwise they will be referred to the current position of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more div at the top like this:

```
<div id="top" style="position: absolute; top: 0"></div>
```

and then provide href as "#top" for all your "back to top" internal links.

```
<a href="#top">back to top</a>
```

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bevvw4zp/2/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not on the "top" (probably links will go into a `<select>`, anyway), but with the cards below.